# How to create a completely new Keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browser, arrow-functions

I am trying to figure out how the working for any new keywords in Javascript is achieved.

For e.g. ES6, Arrow functions can not be used as constructor functions with a new keyword. Also, prototype property does not exist for an arrow function.
I know they bind to the lexical this. This is different than what we have for a normal constructor function.

**So how does our browser understand arrow function.
How can I understand the underlying working of arrow function.**

**How are new features added to JavaScript and how browsers understand it?**

Comment: https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Comment: A Javascript engine is a body of code built to specifically parse and run a given language specification. When a new feature is added to the specification such as arrow functions, a JS engine must add new code to support that new feature.  In the case of an arrow function, they had to modify the parser and they had to create a new type of function that had somewhat different behavior from the regular function object. It came with a `this` binding that was set at the time the function was declared from the current lexical environment at that time rather than set by the way it was called..

Comment: To implement the language engine (e.g. browser) that understands a language, you need to write that language engine in another language. For example Google Chrome and its V8 JS engine is written in C++. So to add the arrow function JS lang feature to V8 engine, some C++ code need to be added to it. Browser need to get updated to newer version so to understand the new language feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments... so when a new version of a browser is shipped, the corresponding JS engine which is in a different language* is upgraded to support the javascript feature analogous to JVM. This would explain for node.js as well as it uses V8. 

In conclusion, we would need the upgraded JS engine to understand any new feature being added javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> How are new features added to JavaScript and how browsers understand it?

New syntax (like arrow functions) and objects (like Promises) are added to the language through [the TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/), administered by the the Ecma TC39 committee.

> The Ecma TC39 committee is responsible for evolving the ECMAScript programming language and authoring the specification.

You can see the link there for a general overview of the various stages a proposal has to go through in order to be added to the language. Once added to the language, a new keyword or object will be exhaustively described in [the official specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), which is intended to describe *all* details of how something is implemented. There's a large focus on making things as deterministic as possible; for the sake of cross-environment compatibility, the committee has to figure out the precise semantics for as many situations as they can. It usually takes quite a lot of discussion and thinking by smart people.

Once the description of the proposal has been mostly finalized, and the proposal has moved to Stage 3 (described in more detail in the first link), environments are expected to start implementing it. So, for example, at this point, you might expect Chrome (V8) and/or Firefox to eventually start shipping new browser versions which contain support for the new syntax (keyword, object, etc), possibly behind a flag.

Once the proposal has had some "in-the-field" implementations, and everything appears to be performing as desired, the ECMAScript editors will integrate the new proposal into the official specification, and the proposal can be said to be "finished".

Another summary of the process can be found [here](https://2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html).

---

For arrow functions in particular, they were added in ES2015, so sometime around 2015, browswers started modifying their Javascript interpreters to process arrow functions as the specification requires. Most browser versions past 2015 understand arrow functions; browsers before 2015 do not. (So, for example, IE11, from 2013, does not and will never understand arrow functions - the specification for arrow functions came out after the browser version was published)

Comment: I guess OP is actually asking about implementation of language feature, not the governance of the language standard. This is answer is legit though.